# CSS background image will not load Django 2.1.2

Tags: html, css, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I am looking for some help regarding this issue. I have researched it to death, I'm relatively new to django and I've hit a wall. My background image will not load from my CSS file. I've tried different directory formats img/image.jpg static/image.jpg etc. I've read as many previous stackoverflow posts as I could for the last three hours along with various tutorials but nothing solved the issue unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance :)

Image directory is: static/img/forrest2.jpg

CSS directory: static/css/style.css

```
Error Codes:
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2074
[24/Nov/2018 14:10:51] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[24/Nov/2018 14:13:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2074
[24/Nov/2018 14:13:29] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1234
[24/Nov/2018 14:14:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2074
[24/Nov/2018 14:14:29] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1235



CSS File:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800|Poppins:500');


html, body{
margin: 0;
padding:0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.intro {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin-auto: auto;
background-image: url('/static/img/forrest2.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
/*Allows the whole image to display*/
display: table;
top: 0;
/*no top white line*/
}


Django Settings in settings.py:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIRS,
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using the `background-image` property to apply all your styles for the background, but [that property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) is only meant to display the image itself and any gradients you want to accompany it.

What you want is the [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) that allows you to add all the values of the background properties (i.e. `background-size`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`, etc) in one line.

Simply replace `background-image` with `background` and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, I'll be able to sleep tonight. This was driving me crazy! I really appreciate your help :)